# Error on rendering angular in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Angular project where in one view you have a list of orders, of those orders you will see only the title, once you click on that title, you should be redirected by the `list.id` to a new view where you would see the full content of the order.

This is the html where you should see the title of that order

```
<a ng-href="#/orders/{{list.id}}" ng-repeat="list in detalleOrden">
   <h5>Orden {{list.id}}</h5>
   <p>{{list.unidadEjec}}</p>       
</a>
```

and here the HTML where you should see the full content of the order. Watch the HTML above `ng-href="#/orders/{{list.id}}"`

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Supervisor</th>
            <td ng-bind="list.supervisor"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Responsable:</th>
            <td>{{list.responsable}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Solicitante:</th>
            <td>{{list.solicitante}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Unidad ejecutora:</th>
            <td>{{list.unidadEjec}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in that I am not using any ng-repeat, should I ?

here the code:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/orders', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'OrderDetailsCtrl',
    resolve: {
      orders: function(Order) {
        return Order.list();
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/orders/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'views/order-detail.html',
    controller: 'OrderIdCtrl',
    resolve: { 
      order: function(Order, $routeParams) {
        Order.list().then(function(orders) {
          for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            if(orders[i].id === $routeParams.id) { 
              return orders[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

controllers

```
  .controller('OrderDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, Order) {

        Order.list().then(function(orders) {
           $scope.detalleOrden = orders;
         }
        });

  .controller('OrderIdCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, Order) {

    $scope.order = {};

    Order.list().then(function(orders) {
      for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
        if(orders[i].id === $routeParams.id) { 
          $scope.order = orders[i];
        }
      }
    }, function() {
      $log('error');
    });
  });
```

and here the service

```
  .factory('Order', function ($q) {    
    return {
      list: function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve([{
          id: '12423',
          title: 'Detalles de la orden',
          supervisor: 'Someone',
          responsable: 'Someone Else',
          solicitante: 'Recope',
          unidadEjec: 'Grupo Planificador Belén'
        }, {
          id: '56456',
          title: 'Detalles de la orden',
          supervisor: 'Carlos Blabla',
          responsable: 'Alberto Blablo',
          solicitante: 'Recope',
          unidadEjec: 'Grupo VEINSA'
        }]);

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

so, my issue: when I click on the title of the order, I am successfully redirected to the new view, but I am unable to visualize the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any `ng-repeat`

and just use `order` instead, look:

```
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Supervisor:</th>
                        <td>{{order.supervisor}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Responsable:</th>
                        <td>{{order.responsable}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Solicitante:</th>
                        <td>{{order.solicitante}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Unidad ejecutora:</th>
                        <td>{{order.unidadEjec}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to use variable `order` instead of `list` in `table`. Am thinking that `table` is in detailed view.

For the uri `/orders/:id` you have `order` variable in controller `OrderIdCtrl`.

Comment: sorry, I did not get you